# Can anyone help me putting the below code in the sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a little help in putting a code in the below sql code.

My code is -

```
torrentlang.name AS lang_name, FROM torrentlang LEFT JOIN torrentlang ON torrentlang = torrentlang.id
```

I want to put it inside the below query:

```
$query  =   "   SELECT
                  torrents.id,
                  torrents.category,
                  torrents.name,
                  torrents.image1,
                  torrents.added,
                  torrents.size,
                  torrents.hits,
                  torrents.banned,
                  torrents.comments,
                  torrents.seeders,
                  torrents.leechers,
                  torrents.times_completed,
                  categories.name          AS cat_name,
                  categories.parent_cat    AS cat_parent
                FROM torrents
                  LEFT JOIN categories
                    ON category = categories.id
                WHERE categories.parent_cat = 'Movies'
                ORDER BY added DESC
                LIMIT 2";
$query12 = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

Please help!

I need the result as below:

```
$query    = "SELECT
              torrents.id,
              torrents.category,
              torrents.name,
              torrents.image1,
              torrents.added,
              torrents.size,
              torrents.hits,
              torrents.banned,
              torrents.comments,
              torrents.seeders,
              torrents.leechers,
              torrents.times_completed,
              categories.name          AS cat_name,
              categories.parent_cat    AS cat_parent
            FROM torrents
              LEFT JOIN categories
                ON category = categories.id,
              torrentlang.name AS lang_name,
              FROM torrentlang
              LEFT JOIN torrentlang
                ON torrentlang = torrentlang.id
            WHERE categories.parent_cat = 'Movies'
                AND torrentlang.id = '3'
            ORDER BY added DESC
            LIMIT 2";
$query12 = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

Please correct the above result code!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: One would also need the table definitions if your problem is joining the queries.

Comment: need to put the above line "torrentlang" in the $query12 without changing any present code

Comment: Please check back the question now

Comment: if you want to join two tables on specific conditions, you need identifiers within on of the tables, pointing to row on the other table. That's why one would need the table definitions, since one can not guess the field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT torrents.id, torrents.category, torrents.name, torrents.image1, torrents.added, torrents.size, torrents.hits, torrents.banned, torrents.comments, torrents.seeders, torrents.leechers, torrents.times_completed, categories.name AS cat_name, categories.parent_cat AS cat_parent ,torrentlang.name AS lang_name
 FROM torrents 
 LEFT JOIN categories ON torrents.id = categories.id  
 LEFT JOIN torrentlang ON torrents.id = torrentlang.id 
 WHERE categories.parent_cat = 'Movies' 
 AND torrentlang.id = 3
 ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 2
```

assuming that `torrents.id = categories.id` and `torrents.id = torrentlang.id`